# how to link an image in my website to open in video player on another page?

Tags: javascript, php, html

I want to link my image that is on my webpage to a video and I want that video will play on another page not on the same page.
so can you help me with it.

Comment: Is it a YouTube video? If not, please specify what type it is and how you're implementing it.

Comment: `<a href="http://domain.com/video"><img src="video.jpg"></a>`?

Comment: Please clarify: "link an image to a video" is unclear; do you want your image to act as a link that opens a new page? Then see @yuriy636's comment. Otherwise, we need to understand what exactly do you mean.

Answer (score 1):

on Your page find your image section try like this.target="_blank" will open the video in other tab

```
   <a href="https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=_Nua3Cjdik0" target="_blank">                   
   <img src="your_image.jpg"></a>
```